# file.open does not work the way I thought it should

Tags: python, file

My code is this:

```
self.data = open("/myData", "a")
self.data.close()

self.data = open ("myData", "r")


    self.master = Tk()       
    if (self.data.read()is not None):
        print 2
        print self.data.readlines()
        print 1
```

I usually get an empty print between the 2 and the one.

I do know for certain that there is something written in myData.
I have tried other methods of opening myData, such as

```
self.data = open ("/myData", "r")
```

which gives me "permission denied" (yes, I do have reading and writing rights on that file, I checked that)

and

```
self.data = open ("/game-engineering/myData", "r")
```

which gives me "file not found".

Am I making some stupid path mistake? I do know for certain that the file is not empty, I see what is in there if I open it by hand.

Comment: If a path is prefixed with "/", it means it's an *absolute* path, which means that it's resolved starting at the root of the filesystem.  I guess you don't want that!  So just remove the leading "/".

Comment: This was my first try. It did not work either.

Comment: Then perhaps your current working directory is incorrect.  Check with `os.path.getcwd()`.  An alternative is explanation is that, despite what you said about permissions, you're actually running Python as some less-privileged user.

Comment: os.path.getcwd() gives me "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getcwd'
"

Comment: my bad. It works without the path. However, the return value is:/home/andrea/game-engineering, so this means I should be in the right directory. It can not be that I am an unprivileged user either: WRITING to a file is just fine.

Comment: `myData` and `/myData` and `/game-engineering/mydata` are three *different* files in that case. The first is likely what you want, and should work with DanielB's answer. The second and third, if they exist, would likely need to be root to do much with. The leading "/" makes it relative to the root of the *whole filesystem*, not to your home directory - you probably meant to try `/home/andrea/myData` and `/home/andrea/game-engineering/myData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `read`, you "consume" the file (the cursor moves to the end of the file) - So when `readlines` is called it immediately hits the EOF and such returns an empty list.

In most cases (with readlines) you can just use it directly, because if the file is empty you'll get an empty list, so you'll never enter the iteration anyway.